# weird segfault in R when using mclapply in Linux

Tags: r, linux, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, mclapply

I have encountered this weird segfault error and have zero clue how to solve it. I was running some Markov Chain Monte Carlo algorithm (a sequential algorithm that approximates a distribution). I parallelize each single iteration of this algorithm. So it is something like

```
for (iter in 1:T){
  res[iter] = mclapply(fun)
}
```

Now the weird thing is when the size of my dataset is relatively moderate, the algorithm can run with no problem. Then I increase the dataset size (80,000 observations, not super large), the algorithm works for the first one thousand iterations and then stop with a `segfault` error. I have pasted the error below:

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x20, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
1: mcfork()
2: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
3: lapply(seq_len(cores), inner.do)
4: mclapply(1:n, FUN = function(k) { return(OptimRE(dataSummaries[[k]], mu + beta, v, vre))}, mc.cores = ncores)
5: getMargLikelihood0(dataSummaries_layer1[[k]], mu, v, vre, beta[k],    logarithm = TRUE)
6: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
7: lapply(X = S, FUN = FUN, ...)
8: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
9: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
10: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
11: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e) if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ") LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")    if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n") .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),     TRUE)) { cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
12: try(lapply(X = S, FUN = FUN, ...), silent = TRUE)
13: sendMaster(try(lapply(X = S, FUN = FUN, ...), silent = TRUE))
14: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
15: lapply(seq_len(cores), inner.do)
16: mclapply(1:length(beta), FUN = function(k) { return(getMargLikelihood0(dataSummaries_layer1[[k]], mu,         v, vre, beta[k], logarithm = TRUE))}, mc.cores = ncores)
17: getMargLikelihood(dataSummaries_layer1, newm, news, newv, beta1)
18: FitPoissRegNRE(my[j, ], groupid, id1, id2, nb = nb, nc = nc,     sig = sig, a = a, b = b, a2 = a2[j], b2 = b2[j], ps_m = ps_m,     ps_s = ps_s, njump = njump)
19: ApplyFitPoissRegNRE(y, hashABC, hashAB, hashA, nb = 200, nc = 800,   sig = 1000, a = 2, b = 2, a2 = rep(100, 3), b2 = rep(5, 3),     ps_m = 0.01, ps_s = 0.03, njump = 4)
20: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
21: eval(ei, envir)
22: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
```

I have googled and some people did encounter this `segfalut` issue in R and what they usually suggested is some version conflict and R should be reinstalled. But the weird thing in my case is that my algorithm works properly in the first thousand iterations. I also ran it without parallelization and it also works fine.

Could anyone suggest what is some possible causes for this? Now I completely have no direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each call to the `mclapply` function may be leaving around zombie processes. Since you're calling it repeatedly, you could be accumulating a huge number of them, eventually causing problems.

You can use the `inline` package to create a function that waits on all child processes to get rid of zombie processes:

```
library(inline)
includes <- '#include <sys/wait.h>'
code <- 'int wstat; while (waitpid(-1, &wstat, WNOHANG) > 0) {};'
wait <- cfunction(body=code, includes=includes, convention='.C')
```

If you call `wait` in the `for` loop after `mclapply`, it should get rid of any zombies and eliminate this as a possible problem:

```
for (iter in 1:T) {
  res[iter] = mclapply(1:10, fun)
  wait()
}
```

Comment: For what it worths, the exact same thing happens with foreach and probably many other parallel package wrapper...

Answer (score 3):

A comment in addition to Steve's suggestion to check for zombie processes: It looks like your code is spawning off recursive `mclapply(..., mc.cores = ncores)` calls;

```
4: mclapply(1:n, FUN = function(k) { return(OptimRE(dataSummaries[[k]], mu + beta, v, vre))}, mc.cores = ncores)
[...]
16: mclapply(1:length(beta), FUN = function(k) { return(getMargLikelihood0(dataSummaries_layer1[[k]], mu, v, vre, beta[k], logarithm = TRUE))}, mc.cores = ncores)
```

In other words, you might end up with "ncores * ncores" forked processes in each iteration.  I don't know what the two `ncores` are here, but make sure to check that this is really what you want.

Comment: This is a good catch! I did have a nested mclapply and I changed that in my current test together with Steve's suggestion and the issues is resolved! The test is time consuming so I cannot do a control test to tell whether the issue is solved by your suggestion or by Steve's. Definitely both helps in terms of stability of the code. I selected Steve's as the answer since it is posted earlier :)